# Div is using the body's background color in IE 7

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, background-color

I have a container div with more divs inside for a slideshow effect. "The container" div is over body's the background image.

CSS for the body:

```
body { background: #333 url(images/bg.jpg) repeat-x top; }
```

Problem is in IE7 the container div has a background color #333. Firefox shows up properly as clear.

Here is the CSS for the container div:

```
.cntdiv {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    overflow:hidden;

    }
```

Any idea why it's picking up the body color and not the image? Again, it works right in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. I was using the jquery.cycle plugin to rotate the divs into view. Somehow IE7 didn't like it. I tried a different jquery plugin and it works perfectly.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

IE7 does indeed support URLs for backgrounds. You are correct in saying that it does not support Data URLs, but this is not a Data URL. A Data URL is CSS looks similar to:

```
url(data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcppV0aCcGCmTIHEIUEqjgaORCMxIC6e0CcguWw6aFjsVMkkIr7g77ZKPJjPZqIyd7sJAgVGoEGv2xsBxqNgYPj/gAwXEQA7) .
```

Note the use of the keyword "data:". The key here is that the data IS the String... not a file.

There are some little catches, however. First, the URL must be in quotes, as in:

```
body { background: #333 url("images/bg.jpg") repeat-x top; }
```

IE does, however, interpret the `background` short syntax differently, so I have found that expanding the syntax helps immensely with IE pre 8 bugs.

```
body { background-color: #333; background-image:url("images/bg.jpg"); 
       background:repeat-x; background-position:top;
}
```

Finally, your container div must be explicitly defined with a background color:

```
.cntdiv {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top:15px;
    overflow:hidden;
/* This is the line that will do it */
    background:transparent;
/* OR EVEN */
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

This code is tested and runs correctly in IE7 and has the same behavior in the others as well. Judicious use of "transparent" is awesome.

It also must be understood that the issue you are facing is not a bug, but a user agent CSS style. This is according to the W3C standards unlike the other `div` bugs that IE has (such as poor `:hover` support). Because you didn't define a background for your `div`, the User Agent (IE7) is allowed to do whatever it likes.  This is true of **all** HTML Elements and **all** browsers. It is why buttons look a certain way unless you change it with the CSS. Explicit definition of every aspect is the best way to overcome little snafus such as these.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks! Given the lack of the use `transparent`, I assumed (possibly incorrectly) that the OP was a novice. I decided that correcting common misconceptions early was probably best. I know if I had had this instruction when I was a novice, my life would have been MUCH easier.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work in IE7 is because you are using a data URL, and IE7 does not support them.  Evidenced by:

http://www.caniuse.com/#search=Data%20url

For IE7 you'll have to use conditional comments and adjust the way you reference the background image.  Here's a quick and simple intro to conditional comments if you don't know about them yet:

http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I've bookmarked the CSS tricks link you provided for additional problems I've come across. However, I did find the source of my problem to be a jquery plugin I was using. Using a different plugin solved my problem. Thanks again!